# how to make get() query with entity in ponyorm

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, ponyorm

I'm using ponyorm. How can I convert this query into one that returns only one result if it exists? 
I want it to throw an error if there is more than one result, similar to the `entity.get()` query.

```
url = 'some url'
access= select(c for c in Access if c.people_url.lower().startswith(url))
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`get`](https://docs.ponyorm.com/api_reference.html#Query.get) method of a query:

```py
url = 'some url'
query = select(c for c in Access if c.people_url.lower().startswith(url))
obj = query.get()
```

This method throws `MultipleObjectsFoundError` if more than one object was found